# Private IPV4 address space usage statistics (Least Used)

Tags: networking, vpn, ip-address, private-ip

I'm trying to avoid IP conflicts with wireguard VPN and would like to select the least used private IPV4 address block.

Are there any statistics published on usage of private IPV4 address space?  Or perhaps some studies?

Comment: Why can't you use rfc-1918 addresses? It's pretty rare that someone's allocated all their private ip addresses. Did you double check that the local network isn't using only part of a private ip netblock (like if your computer is on 192.168.1.5/24 then 192.168.2-255.* is free).

Comment: I am using the RFC-1918 addresses (hence why I said private address).  A VPN client may encounter private IP networks all over the world (hotels, airports, etc).  I've personally run into conflicts many times.  That is why I ask if there is any statistical data regarding which IP blocks are used the least.  Otherwise, I'm just randomly gambling.

Comment: Oic, whoops sorry, The 172.16.0.0/20 netblock is by far the least used.

Comment: How far along is your IPv6 deployment? You can provide VPNs and services from a globally unique net.

Comment: This is a great question. You'd think somebody would have done a survey of public wifi hotspots, hotels etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to accurately know, and most organizations wouldn't publish or divulge their internal IP addressing scheme.

That being said, of the three RFC 1918 address ranges available, I've found in my experience that addresses in the 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 range are the least used.

Comment: OK.  I was not sure if there were any studies done (ie. sampling of default address ranges from various routers, etc)

Comment: You could probably research the default address space configuration for various router manufacturers, but that doesn't guarantee that those defaults are maintained once those routers are deployed.

Comment: Docker's default appears to be 172.17.0.0/16 (unless it detects a conflict in which case it apparently tries 172.18 and 172.19 next).
AWS VPC allocates 172.31.0.0/16 as the default VPC for each region and Ec2 instances are created in /20 subnets eg 172.31.0.0/20, 172.31.16.0/20, 172.31.32.0/20
I have seen 192.168.0 and 192.168.1 and 10.0.0 used for SOHO modem/routers.
ChatGPT suggests 172.16.0.0/24 or 172.16.1.0/24 are sometimes used as well